# How to determine which row in contacts database has been updated

Tags: android

I am writing a backup application and need to know which records in the contacts database have been updated, so that I can backup only those records. I have looked at the documentation and it seems that there is a "DIRTY" constant field in ContactsContract.RawContacts class, which is supposed to be set to "1", for the rows that are  updated. But it is not clear to me as to when will this field get cleared to "0". Can someone provide me example code on how to use this? Can this field be used to determine if a contact has been added or updated?
If this is not the correct way to achieve what I am trying to do can anyone suggest me another way. I am also aware that I can use the RegisterContentObserver() call to identify whenever there is a change in the Contacts database but this will require my application to be running always in the background, which is way too expensive and I do not want to do that.
If there is anyway to extract the timestamp when the various contacts have been added or updated that would be perfect too, but I cannot find how to do that.
Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: user887304 how did you solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have looked at the documentation and it seems that there is a "DIRTY" constant field in ContactsContract.RawContacts class, which is supposed to be set to "1", for the rows that are updated. But it is not clear to me as to when will this field get cleared to "0".

In my experience, whenever there is a 'dirty' indicator of some sort, it is the responsibility of the backup/sync app to reset it once the data has been successfully committed during a backup/sync operation.

This can cause problems, however, when more than one application is used - the first one run at any time after data has been updated will reset the flag and the next one run wont find anything to backup/sync.

In this case if you require that a user is able to use a 'sync' app (for example) but you also want to have a 'backup' operation then registering a ContentObserver would serve a better purpose and there's no reason why this should be 'expensive' on resources if implemented correctly.

**EDIT:** Although there is no 'timestamp' there is a 'VERSION' field which is updated (which is when 'DIRTY' is set). If you backup this field, you could simply leave the 'DIRTY' flag set and compare current VERSION in the contacts DB with your most recent backup.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I will check the "VERSION" field for changes. This seems to be a simpler implementation than registering a ContentObserver.

Comment: Can you please tell me the query to retrieve the VERSION field.I am concern about http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html this,but cannot find a clue

Comment: @kgandroid: I think you can just add `RawContacts.VERSION` as one of the elements in the `String[]` passed as the `projection` argument to `getContentResolver().query(...)` call as shown in the example code in the link you posted.